# Angular CLI app not working on IE 10

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer-10

[image]I have added `shim.min.js` and `shims_for_IE.js` in my `index.html` file.

Here is my file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test Manager</title>
        <base href="/">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
        <script src="assets/ie/shim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/ie/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/ie/web-animations.min.js"></script>

    </head>
```

The app is working fine in Chrome, Firefox and IE 11.

But it is not working in IE 10. In IE 10 it's not updating DOM. It's getting stuck.

Comment: Any errors in your console? How are you running IE 10? If you have IE 11 installed, you must be using a separate VM or another computer. The emulation of older IE versions provided by the IE 11 dev tools is useful but not exact.

Comment: @AluanHaddad  there is no error in console. I have only IE10 installed on my machine.

Comment: This is not enough information to debug your problem. You need to narrow down and isolate the issue.

Comment: @torazaburo  what kind of information you need. I also added a screenshot of IE10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what else you are running I suppose, 
I can remember 3 hurdles for IE10,  I will add some more if I remember.

1) I needed to add at least 1 locale with intl;

```
import 'intl';
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en.js';
```

2) The usual IE stuff like, an example might be something like:

```
var st = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
```

3) I needed a mutation observer shim but that's only because I'm using material2 I believe.
https://github.com/megawac/MutationObserver.js

There are also many required shims - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html

angular-cli also has a *polyfills.ts* preset with all of the important shims.

Comment: Angular material2 button, tab are not working after some time. Normal Bootstrap Buttons, Links are working fine. But material2 not working in ie10

Comment: On #2 I just picked a random example,  just an example of some js that needs to be different for IE.   Do you have any more errors showing now that it runs?

Comment: Actually, On scrolling up or down the page Only Material2 buttons, navigation links are becoming unclickable because   the class    
    .cdk-overlay-container {
        position: fixed;
        z-index:1000;
    }      automatically added by material2. I have removed this  .cdk-overlay-container class. Now everything is working fine except material2 dialog that is not working in ie10.   Thanks, Your answer helps me a lot.

Comment: On localhost ist working fine but on production, it not looks good. I mean header is not fixed on Production but it is fixed by CSS